# Can Dafny be used non-interactively, for example from a python program?

Tags: dafny

I would like to query whether a particular Dafny program verifies. Dafny is typically used to develop programs in an interactive manner inside the visual studio IDE.

However, I need to perform the query in a non-interactive manner. In particular I need to query Dafny from within a python program. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `dafny.exe` from python, passing as an argument the name of a file that contains the dafny program that you wish to verify. Please see this [other answer on how to call external commands from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).

You can get help on the dafny command line arguments by running `dafny.exe` with the `/?` switch.

You will need to **parse the output of dafny to determine if the verification was successful**. The [dafny test suite](https://dafny.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Test/) works in this manner.

You might like to look at the [code of this project](https://github.com/lexicalscope/dafnyserverui) which does something similar, but from Java.

Comment: Thnaks a lot that is a great help